# Why Does 'elif' bypass 'if' in my python function

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to get the expiry date out of string with a function as follows

```
p = 'Chiet TS Officer ~ ae\nOriginal Registration Date: 1998-06-17 ective Date: 2018-06-20\n\nLatest Revision Date: 2018-05-24 Expiry Date: 2021-06-19\nPage: 1 of 1\n\n \n\n.. making excellence a habit”\n\x0c'
def enddate(p):    
    for line in p.lower().split('\n'):
        if "exp" in line:
            try:
                return(str(dparser.parse(line.split("exp")[-1],fuzzy=True))[0:10])
            except:
                try:
                    return(str(dparser.parse(line),fuzzy=True))[0:10]
                except:
                    return(str(dparser.parse(line.split("20")[-1],fuzzy=True))[0:10])
        elif "20" in line:
            try:
                return(str(dparser.parse(line.split("20")[-1],fuzzy=True))[0:10])
            except:
                return("error")
enddate(p)

'error'
```

you see that `elif` bypassed `if`, if I deleted the `elif` part it would work well

```
p = 'Chiet TS Officer ~ ae\nOriginal Registration Date: 1998-06-17 ective Date: 2018-06-20\n\nLatest Revision Date: 2018-05-24 Expiry Date: 2021-06-19\nPage: 1 of 1\n\n \n\n.. making excellence a habit”\n\x0c'
def enddate(p):    
    for line in p.lower().split('\n'):
        if "exp" in line:
            try:
                return(str(dparser.parse(line.split("exp")[-1],fuzzy=True))[0:10])
            except:
                try:
                    return(str(dparser.parse(line),fuzzy=True))[0:10]
                except:
                    return(str(dparser.parse(line.split("20")[-1],fuzzy=True))[0:10])
enddate(p)

'2021-06-19'
```

so why does that happen? and how can I make my function look for `"20"` only if all `line`s don't contain `"exp"`?

Comment: so what is your error??

Comment: The `elif` will cause your function to return from the loop iteration for the first "20"-`line`. Removing the `elif` will make your loop reach a later `line` with `"exp"` in it, and only then return.

Comment: @JayPeerachai Did I mention there was one?,
@schwobaseggl But What if I want my function to to look for `"20"` only if all `line`s don't contain `"exp"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply because "2018" is on the second line, while "expiry" is on the third. So in your case #2, first line nothing happens, second line you enter the elif condition and it returns the error. In case #1, nothing happens until the third line, and then you enter the fist if condition.

Comment: Oh. Got it, But I want my function to to look for `"20"` only if all lines don't contain `"exp"` how can I do that?

Comment: The naive solution would just be to iterate over all lines first, only searching for "exp", and if and only if you find no "exp" in either of the lines, you can then reiterate over all lines now searching for "20".

Comment: A better solution would probably just be to search for "exp" in the original string (without doing the split), and start looping on the lines if you don't find it.